# How to disable LoadMask on GridPanel

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I've a GridPanel which is updated every 10 seconds.

```
var refreshEnvironmentsStoreTask = {
    run: function() {
        this.getEnvironmentsStore().load()
    },
    scope: this,
    interval: 10000 //10 second
}
Ext.TaskManager.start(refreshEnvironmentsStoreTask);
```

As result of frequent updates on the grid appears flicker. I want to disable LoadMask but next code doesn't work:

```
Ext.define('MyGrid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store : 'Environments',
    viewConfig: {
        loadMask: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP never shed any light on this and I was looking for it today, the answer is that this will work in versions of ExtJS after 4.01. I am using it now:

```
Ext.define('MyGrid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store : 'Environments',
    viewConfig: {
        loadMask: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a simple page and disabling it there before doing it on your page? It seems your setting the default which is false to false.

[Ext.LoadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.LoadMask)

[Ext.ComponentLoader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.ComponentLoader-cfg-loadMask)

Comment: Thanks for response. I've already found solution. This is a extjs 4.0.1 bug.